# FakeHttpServer breaks when upgrading to Jetty 9

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I am migrating an application that used Jetty 7.4.5.v20110725 to Jetty 9.3.0.M2, using Maven. I already had upgraded the `javax.servlet-api` to 3.1.0.

But I am using the [FakeHttpServer version 0.3.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/se.dannej/fakehttpserver/0.3.0) for tests, and at this time there is no newer version. It uses the `org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector` class that used to exist up to Jetty 8.x, but does not exists anymore in Jetty 9.

Currently my projects breaks at runtime with a `NoClassDefFoundError` due to the removed class in Jetty that FakeHttpServer tries to use, holding me back from upgrading Jetty. What can I do to fix that?

<sup>Note, this was also cross-posted in the Portuguese StackOverflow version: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/64548/132</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade the code that uses Jetty on FakeHttpServer for Jetty 9.

That is your only choice if you want to use Jetty 9 with FakeHttpServer.

Looking at the [project page for FakeHttpServer](https://bitbucket.org/jideji/fakehttpserver), it seems that there have been no updates (commits) to the project tree since Dec 2012.

You'll either have to convince the project leads to update it, or do it yourself.

Comment: Darn, there is no easy way of doing it? Like an extra dependency with an adapter somewhere for the missing classes? In fact both Jetty and FakeHttpServer are transitive dependencies in my project, and I was forced to upgrade Jetty to resolve some other dependency problem in Maven. This is severely complicating and overflowing my estimated change scope.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Jetty contains several ways of testing webapps.    Look at the unit tests in the jetty source code and I'm sure you will find the equivalent of FakeHttpServer.

ServletTester comes to mind as one example. Or just create a Server using the LocalConnector is another way.

Comment: This is not the problem. The problem is the dependency breaking in maven.